# Setup a good game servers?

Tags: hosting, gameserver

I have a very bad experience in setting up a game server. My fail experience was that I put all the servers into one (mail, database, game and web server). In the end, mail server did not handle mails properly (cant send X number of emails), database and web getting slower and slower, not enough hardisk spaces etc.

My game requirements:

- Flash engine
- Mysql database for store users data
- Web page
- Sending emails (like newsletters every month or weekly)

After some readings, assume cost is not a problem (well, dont let my client knows about it). My current plan is:

- 1 server for mail(btw, i still have trauma about the mail server, cant sent emails to all users previously)
- 1 server for the app (web, flash games)
- 1 server for database
- ?? Do I need a backup server here??

Are those enough?

My next question is, how to link up those servers, i.e the mail + database server link to app(web) server.

And, how to do load-balancing?

I have been readings, searching the web, but I still could not really understand. Sooo, please advise.

Comment: use google apps for mail and mail chimp for bulk mailing ;)

Comment: @anthony: Thats something new to me. Sounds like a great idea. Few questions to ask: Are you saying, when sending emails we use mail chimp, when receiving we use our own email? Second, that one need to pay (i know its worth the money), but can I use gmail SMTP and send to my users instead of using this? Will it decrease the % to reach my users? Oh shit, more questions, but no characters left

Comment: Pay me £400/day, and I'll contract to you for the sysadmin services.

Comment: you use google apps for general email send and recieve. and something like mailchimp for bulk email sending to lots of people

Answer (score 3):

Hire a good sysadmin who knows how to do these things.

It will be more than worth the investment.

Comment: I was told to pick this skills, sysadmin. Jack-of-all-trades.

Comment: Here is the skillset you'll need: System architect, system administrator, network administrator. From your question I deduce you know little about these fields (no offence intended, but you don't). These aren't things you can just explain in a few words. So the logical thing to do, if you need that job done for a production system, is hire someone who knows about this. BTW, if you use some form of cloud service (Like Amazone EC2), you might save quite a bit of money on running expenses.